# ¿Porque me da el error "IndexError: list index out of range" usando lamda?

Tags: python, lambda

Estoy intentando codear un algoritmo para calcular estimaciones de integrales (Específicamente la cuadratura de *Gauss-Legendre*), pero estoy teniendo problemas para definir funciones dentro del bucle `for`, el código es el siguiente:

```
from sympy import integrate, init_printing
from sympy.abc import x
P = [lambda x : 0,lambda x : 1]
print('p_{-1}(x)=',P[0](x),' p_0(x)=',P[1](x))
A = []
B = [1]
print('A=',A)
print('B=',B)
n=4
for i in range (n):
  print('i=',i)
  A.append(integrate(x*P[i+1](x)*P[i+1](x),(x,-1,1))/integrate(P[i+1](x)*P[i+1](x),(x,-1,1))) #en la segunda iteración del bucle me da que el indice esta fuera de rango. 
  print('A=',A)
  P.append(lambda x : (x-A[i])*P[i+1](x)-B[i]*P[i](x)) #y luego respite el error aqui. 
  print('p_{i+2}(x)=',P[i+2](x))
  B.append(integrate(P[i+2](x)*P[i+2](x),(x,-1,1))/integrate(P[i+1](x)*P[i+1](x),(x,-1,1)))
  print('B=',B)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `P.append(lambda x : (x-A[i])*P[i+1](x)-B[i]*P[i](x))`
con esta linea estaria intentado agregarle un elemento más.
Por eso, intento leer `P[i+1]`.

Comment: Entiendo que la linea `P.append(lambda x : (x-A[i])*P[i+1](x)-B[i]*P[i](x))` agraga `P[2]` en la primer iteración del for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

El problema es que cuando evalúas `lambda` adentro del `for` utilizas `i` para calcular el valor del siguiente elemento de la lista, entonces en `lambda` se hace referencia al valor actual de `i` por lo que en la segunda iteración también se modifica el valor de `i` dentro de lambda

Ejemplo sencillo

```
y = []
for i in range(3):
    y.append(lambda x: x + i)
```

En la primera iteración el valor del índice 0 se crea como `lambda x: x + i` y en esta iteración `i` vale 0.

En la segunda iteración `i` vale 1, pero como `i` también está en `lambda` del índice 0 entonces también se modifica ese valor, es decir, `i` siempre toma el valor actual de la iteración para todas las funciones `lambda` que la contengan

Para arreglarlo puedes indicar que en la función `lambda` el valor de `i` siempre va a traducirse a un valor numérico que será constante sin importar las iteraciones (Digamos que congelamos el valor de `i` para cada `lambda`)

En el ejemplo genérico que puse anteriormente sería:

```
y = []
for i in range(3):
    y.append(lambda x, i=i: x + i)
```

Aplicándolo a tu código quedaría así:

```
from sympy import integrate, init_printing
from sympy.abc import x
P = [lambda x : 0,lambda x : 1]
print('p_{-1}(x)=',P[0](x),' p_0(x)=',P[1](x))
A = []
B = [1]
print('A=',A)
print('B=',B)
n=4
for i in range (n):
    print('i=',i)
    A.append(integrate(x*P[i+1](x)*P[i+1](x),(x,-1,1))/integrate(P[i+1](x)*P[i+1](x),(x,-1,1))) #en la segunda iteración del bucle me da que el indice esta fuera de rango. 
    print('A=',A)
    P.append(lambda x, i=i : (x-A[i])*P[i+1](x)-B[i]*P[i](x)) #y luego respite el error aqui. 
    print('p_{i+2}(x)=',P[i+2](x))
    B.append(integrate(P[i+2](x)*P[i+2](x),(x,-1,1))/integrate(P[i+1](x)*P[i+1](x),(x,-1,1)))
    print('B=',B)
```

Comment: Era eso!! Muchisimas gracias!!!

Comment: No hay de que, de hecho también lo acabo de aprender, tuve que investigar y probar lo que estaba pasando. Saludos!

Comment: Tiene mucho que ver con que i, al existir fuera del lambda, es buscada por Python fuera de éste. Entonces cuando el lambda es llamado luego del bucle for, obtiene del ambito no-local la variable i, que por supuesto tendrá de valor el obtenido en la ultima iteración del for en este caso particular.